# Get comments from pptx slide

Tags: r, officer

I was wondering if there's a way from `officer` to capture the comments of a slide / add comments to a slide in PPTX?

I'm interested in using R to autoupdate an existing PPTX slide deck. When a reviewer makes a comment on a slide that gets autoupdated, I want that comment to persist after the deck is regenerated.

Using `officer::pptx_summary()`, I can see things like text, tables, etc. for each slide in my deck, but not comments or location of comments.